# Crop a large point cloud with GeoJSON defining the geometries of sub point cloud

Tags: geojson, clip, lidar, point-cloud, pdal

I have a large point cloud (a city model) and would like to get the point clouds of every building in the city. I already have the GeoJSON file with the geometries of every single building in the city. I know that PDAL could do the trick but it seems that I have to clip the buildings one by one, and it would take way too much time given the size of the point cloud and the number of buildings. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

PDAL's `filters.overlay` is not particularly efficient if you give it lots of geometries. I [recently added](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/pull/3815) a `bounds` filter option to it that you could set to the buffered bounds of each building, and then run a pipeline for each.

Making this scenario work out-of-the-box with PDAL without multi-staging it would require some development effort. Contact us if you want to support that with code contribution or other resources.